# Where to install/ unpack android studio in ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, android, android-studio, android-sdk, ubuntu-for-android

I have recently dual booted ubuntu alongside windows, and my partitions for ubuntu are as follows-

*80 Gb - "/"   Uses SSD (For root) *

*100 Gb - "/home"    Uses Hard Disk (For Home)*

But now when I try to install android studio in **/opt** or **/usr/local** then to run the android studio I need root user permissions every time, and also I am not able to directly create desktop entry from android studio. 
However, I have manually created desktop entry, but it also doesn't run because it needs root user permissions.

So, I just want to know that how I can install my android studio in my SSD because my **/home** uses HDD.
Or 
Where should I extract my tar/zip file so as to run android studio normally without using root permissions again and again.

I am just a beginner in ubuntu, so any help would be really appreciated, or if you can give links to any resources that would be really helpful as I am constantly trying to install android studio normally.

Answer (score 3):

It’s not too complicated:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Install Java:

   ```
   sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
   ```
3. Install Android Studio:

   ```
   sudo snap install android-studio --classic
   ```
4. Open Android Studio from the application menu or, if you prefer the terminal:

   ```
   android-studio
   ```

No need to make it too complicated

Comment: $ANDROID_HOME, path for the same?